# Return values from BroadcastReceiver (Bluetooth)

Tags: java, android, asynchronous, bluetooth

I'm trying to make a bluetooth chat by implementing my own android bluetooth library. I would like to have a clear separation between the graphic part and the logical part (for the modularity).

To get the list of bluetooth devices, I registered programatically a new BroadcastReceiver in my *BluetoothManager* class (library).

I would like to return or store these values in a array within this class so that I can access them from my (external) activity/fragment.

How should I do this?

**This is the code from the BluetoothManager (library):**

```
public class BluetoothManager {

    private BluetoothAdapter bluetoothAdapter;
    private Context context;

    public BluetoothManager(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        this.bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        if (bluetoothAdapter == null) {
            Log.d("[BluetoothManager]", "Error device does not support Bluetooth");
        }
    }

    // Create a BroadcastReceiver for ACTION_FOUND.
    private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object and its info from the Intent.
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                // Add value into an array or return --> TODO 
            }
        }
    };

    public void discovery(){
        // Check if the device is already "discovering". If it is, then cancel discovery.
        if (bluetoothAdapter.isDiscovering()) {
            bluetoothAdapter.cancelDiscovery();
        }
        // Start Discovery
        bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
        // Register for broadcasts when a device is discovered.
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
        context.getApplicationContext().registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    }

    ...

}
```

**This is the code from the fragment:**

```
public class TabFragment extends ListFragment implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

private BluetoothManager bluetoothManager;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab_fragment2, container, false);

    Button button = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            bluetoothManager = new BluetoothManager(getContext());
            if(bluetoothManager.activeBluetooth()){
                bluetoothManager.discovery();
                // Get Values here --> TODO
            }
        }
    });

    // Add return values into a list
    //final String[] items = ...;
    final ArrayAdapter<String> aa = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, items);
    setListAdapter(aa);

    return fragmentView;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Discovering a list of available bluetooth devices is asynchronous. On receiving the broadcast, BluetoothManager class could save the updated list of devices in a list member variable and expose a public getter method to retrieve it from Activity or fragment. Also, consider exposing a listener to your activity to provide the updated list since devices can keep getting added or removed dynamically. At any point in time, the UI should refresh itself on receiving the updated list of devices.

`public void onClick(View v) {
            bluetoothManager = new BluetoothManager(getContext()); ...}`

is a bad idea. You must ideally instantiate your BluetoothManager class in onCreate of your activity or fragment so it gets lead time to discover the list of devices well before the user clicks the button.

My recommendation would be:

1. Instantiate BluetoothManager in onCreate of Activity, change the constructor to accept a callback object to notify when the list of devices change.
2. Listen to the Broadcast in BluetoothManager to identify addition or deletion of devices. Update your local list and whenever an update happens, notify the UI's callback
3. Implement the callback in the activity/fragment and update the UI whenever you receive updates from BluetoothManager class
4. When user clicks the button, call the BluetoothManager to fetch updated list of devices and update your UI.
5. Unregister the Broadcast that was registered in BluetoothManager from onDestroy of your activity (**Extremely important. Else will lead to memory leaks**)

Alternatively, If you would like to share the Bluetooth manager instance with multiple activities, make BluetoothManager a singleton and register BroadcastReceiver with application context. Please ensure to unregister the BroadcastReceiver when all your activities are destroyed and you dont need the receiver anymore.

**UPDATE:**
Callback could just be an interface implemented by your activity or fragment. Sample code below:

```
        public interface BluetoothDevicesAvailable {
    void onBluetoothDeviceListChanged(List<BluetoothDevice> deviceList);
    }

    public class SomeActivity implements BluetoothDevicesAvailable {
    //... Some code

    @Override
    public void onBluetoothDeviceListChanged(List<BluetoothDevice> deviceList) {
    //Add your logic here to update UI
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Do you have any example for the callback object?

Answer (score 1):

You can not return a value form Broadcast receiver as its event driven. What you can do is in onReceive() You can save these values to a Collection globally (within same class or a in a Singleton wrapper class) and then use it throughout the application.

To send callback of values updates an another local Broadcast receiver will be helpful.